# How can I drop a shadow of an image on an another image below it in css and html?

Tags: html, image, css

```
<html>
  <head>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>        
  <body>
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
    <div id="linker">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="img1.png"></a>
      <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="tw.png"></a>        
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I add a shadow to pic1 to pic2. Is there any way to drop shadow like one one another?

Comment: Interesting, you asked a question showing just HTML, asking about CSS and expecting us to know how your HTML actually looks like one the page. it would need us to pull out the crystal globe to answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop shadows do not overlap elements on the same z-level. Use `position: relative` (or absolute) and use `z-index` to change the level of your elements.

Put the one on front higher up, something like:

```
#linker a:first-child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'   < /* for the first item- facebook*/

```
#linker a:first-child
{

Position: relative;
Z-index: 2;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}

/* for the second item- twitter*/
#linker a:nth-child(2)
{

Position: relative;
Z-index: 1; /* underneath facebook*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray; /* if you want a shadow from twitter*/
box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
} >'
```